# Control the order of git add -p?

Tags: git

Is there a way to control the order of files checked by "git add -p"? In particular, it would be nice if it checked in header/source order. That is, if I have a list of all the paths that are modified, I would like to sort it by filename, but with .h and .hpp before .c and .cpp.

Comment: Maybe `git add -p *.{h,c}` ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why?

Comment: Why? Because when they come at me in random order it takes a little extra thought to decide if the hunk belongs to the logical feature I'm trying to add for this commit.

Comment: I'd suggest to use a graphical tool instead for this use case, like `git citool`.

Comment: It looks like I could use `git ls-files -m` to get the list of files it would use, then sort that the way I want, then pass that as the `<pathspec>` argument to `git add -p`.